# Typescript base class with typed create and patch methods

Tags: typescript

I want to create next api:

```js
class BaseModel {
  // has 2 generic methods
  static create(props) { //... }

  patch(props) { //... }
}

class Foo extends BaseModel { //... }

// someProps should be typechecked
const foo = Foo.create(someProps)

// patchProps should be typechecked too
foo.patch(patchProps)
```

I came up with next solution (it is probably not optimal at all):

```js
type PropType<T, P extends keyof T> = T[P];

class BaseModel {
  static create<T extends typeof BaseModel & { props: unknown }, P extends PropType<T, 'props'>>(
    this: T,
    props: P
  ): InstanceType<T> {
    const model = new this() as InstanceType<T>;

    model.patch(props);

    return model;
  }

  // @ts-ignore
  // Don't know how to type this part
  patch(props) {
    // some work, might be untyped
  }
}

class Foo extends BaseModel {
  static props: {
    someString?: string;
  };
}

// this works fine
const t = Foo.create({ someString: 'someString' });

// this is not typechecked, should throw error
t.patch({ someInvalidObject: 1 });
```

I do not declare `props` in BaseModel so it should be required to declare on children class.

How do I make `patch` method strongly typed?
Maybe there is some other way to make this api work?

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20PropType%3CT%2C%20P%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%20T%5BP%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20BaseModel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20create%3CT%20extends%20typeof%20BaseModel%20%26%20%7B%20props%3A%20unknown%20%7D%2C%20P%20extends%20PropType%3CT%2C%20'props'%3E%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20props%3A%20P%0D%0A%20%20)%3A%20InstanceType%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20model%20%3D%20new%20this()%20as%20InstanceType%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20model.patch(props)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20model%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20%40ts-ignore%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Don't%20know%20how%20to%20type%20this%20part%0D%0A%20%20patch(props)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20some%20work%2C%20might%20be%20untyped%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20extends%20BaseModel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20props%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20someString%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20works%20fine%0D%0Aconst%20t%20%3D%20Foo.create(%7B%20someString%3A%20'someString'%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20is%20not%20typechecked%0D%0At.patch(%7B%20someInvalidObject%3A%201%20%7D)%3B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can add a generic type parameter to the base class, although that will make it difficult when inheriting the class.

Another option is the base class to have a version of the method which is basically un-callable. Then we add a the apropriate signature of `patch` as the return of `create`

```
type PropType<T, P extends keyof T> = T[P];

class BaseModel {
  static create<T extends typeof BaseModel & { props: unknown }, P extends PropType<T, 'props'>>(
    this: T,
    props: P
  ) {
    const model = new this() as InstanceType<T> & {
      patch(props: T['props']): void
    };

    model.patch(props);

    return model;
  }

  patch(props: Record<string, never>) {

  }
}

class Foo extends BaseModel {
  static props: {
    someString?: string;
  };
}


const t = Foo.create({ someString: 'someString' });

t.patch({ someInvalidObject: 1 }); //err
t.patch({ someString: "" }) // ok
```

Comment: Wow, interesting solution! Although it looks a little bit like a hack, but works nicely. I'll stick with it for now, thank you very much.

Comment: @O4epegb It's not ideal, you could also use omit to take out the `BaseModel ` version of `patch` in the returned type and keep the base definition with `any`.